# Pygame error in Python 2.7

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently working on Particle Swarm Optimisation SVM, am using pygame for visualisation. Currently on processing the data am getting error in it on rectangle parameter.

This is the code:

```
pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255,0,0), (x - size, y - size, size*2, size*2))
```

and:

> TypeError: Rect argument is invalid.

Comment: You only have three arguments, you should add a forth argument for the thickness.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991300/pygame-draw-rect-has-invalid-parameters

Comment: @Will The width is an optional argument that defaults to 0 (which will fill the rect). http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect

Comment: Tried replicate the error in Python 2.7.10 and pygame 1.9.2b6 but was unable. The problem must be either dependent on your version or you've given the wrong error messages. To easier find an answer you should post your pygame version as well as [mcve].

Comment: Pro tips for good questions: don't add 'ASAP' and other forms of begging, and don't ask for people to do your work.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have included the Surface and Color arguments but your rect is invalid because you're creating your rect on the fly, by giving rect initiation arguments.

What you should do is :

```
rect = pygame.rect((50,50), (25,60)) # X, Y, Width and Height
pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255,0,0), rect)
```

Here, have a look at the pygame wiki [about draw](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) if you need more info